# Why is nothing being displayed on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, d3.js

The file "LoanStats3a.csv" is in the same folder. Yet somehow this is not working. Also I am diving the x and y values fort he lines because the amount is too large, however, this should assign them normal values.

```
<html>
<title>Loans</title>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
    #LoanStats3a {
        color: blueviolet;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <script>
        d3.csv("LoanStats3a.csv", function (file1) {
            var bg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 5000)
                .attr("height", 5000);

            var data1 = [{
                    x: d.loan_amnt,
                    y: d.term
                },
                {
                    x: d.int_rate,
                    y: d.annual_inc
                },
                {
                    x: d.member_id,
                    y: d.id
                }
            ];

            var group = bg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate (100,100)");
            var line = d3.svg.line("line")
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d.x / 100;
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d.y / 100;
                });

            bg.selectAll("path")
                .data(file1)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("cx", 500)
                .attr("cy", 500)
                .attr("d", line)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", 20);
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Furthermore, here is the code when I use local data and still nothing is displayed:

```
<html>


<title>Loans</title>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<style>
    #LoanStats3a {
        color: blueviolet;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <script>
        d3.csv("LoanStats3a.csv", function (file1) {
            var bg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 5000)
                .attr("height", 5000);

            var data1 = [
                //{x:d.loan_amnt , y : d.term},
                //{x:d.int_rate , y : d.annual_inc},
                //{x:d.member_id , y : d.id}
                {
                    x: 10,
                    y: 20
                },
                {
                    x: 30,
                    y: 40
                },
                {
                    x: 50,
                    y: 60
                }

            ];

            var group = bg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate (100,100)");
            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d.x / 100;
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d.y / 100;
                });

            bg.selectAll("path")
                .data([data1])
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("cx", 500)
                .attr("cy", 500)
                .attr("d", line)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", 20);

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: /   {x:d.loan_amnt , y : d.term}, ..forward slash seems to be causing syntax error

Comment: Fixed that and the same issue.

Comment: can you provide sample data of loanStat3a.csv for testing where it is failing

Comment: Try  .attr("d", line(data1))

Comment: Please try testing with hard coded data in place of csv data ..to see whether it is issue with reading file data or script issue

Comment: I did, am having the same issue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?. A graph bars, a line graph, and scatter plot?

Comment: from the code, you are trying to append path, circle and line....right???

Comment: Eventually I want to build multiple interactive paths that get their data from multiple csv files.

Comment: @NagaSaiA I tried the ".attr("d",line(data1))" suggestion. Doesnt change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem

You are not that far off

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 5000)
    .attr("height", 5000)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(80)
    .outerRadius(100)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle((100 * Math.PI)-1);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", arc);
```

```css
.arc {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i took the liberty of renaming your vars and 'slimlining' your code

Comment: this is purely an answer to the 'how to display an arc' issue, dunno about csvs, but it would help matters if you actually had a div of that id in the body?

Comment: It does help, thank you! I know how to import data from a csv and make a circle, however, it is hard putting specific data from the csv file and putting it in an array. Thats where the challenge lies in my case.